# facebook access token error

Tags: php, facebook, access-token

Please help me to solve the following error.

> Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/australi/public_html/fb/index.php on line 27
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=AAABempp6Ls0BANc98WmqZAreBbUzPnT1xyer9wtPmbvlwsnZCc4AKwuvCAVosLxw4yItvOkDoIK5hyCvBPZAk90nLx4PZACorrZCZAAi9pGgZDZD) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/australi/public_html/fb/index.php on line 27
>   Invalid Access Token

Comment: Can you add more information about what you want to do and what you have tried so far?

Comment: ok thank you here this is the website um try to develop this can make fb likes i just buy it but now seller not responding  http://e4d4.lk/fb/

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you need to allow the wrapper in your php.ini config file.

Comment: This isn't an answer... Please use comments section

Comment: can you help me more because i have small  knowledge about php

Comment: Go to wherever your server's PHP config is and change allow_url_fopen to 1 or true - if you don't know how to, Google can probably help find a step by step guide